# Fastlane increment_build_number for all targets?

Tags: ios, xcode, fastlane

I've got project with one file i.e. `myApp.xcodeproj` and it has 2 targets (simply to replace some config files / icons / names etc...)

I noticed that when I run fastlane 
`increment_build_number(xcodeproj: "myApp.xcodeproj")` it increments version only of the original target I had. Is there a way for me to increment it on all targets at once? I don't even mind them all being unified together somehow.

Note: second target has its own info.plist file with some values tweaked. Also not sure if it helps, but both are inside a workspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve it by writing only **increment_build_number** in Fastfile.